# How to remove package dsfont on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, fonts

I used the answer of  [How to install dsfont package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96873/how-to-install-dsfont-package) to solve my problem with my TeX editor,but my problem got worst. I want to remove this package to return to initial step and find another way to solve my problem. May you please help me to remove that? I just want to return to the before applying this command.

Comment: Which of the answers did you use, i.e. how did you install it?

Comment: I used the first answer. I used Terminal. I used "sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra"

Comment: Then do: `sudo apt purge texlive-fonts-extra` and maybe also `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: The initial error for my text editor is : "dsfont.sty" not found. I do not know how to solve that!

Comment: Then I would suggest that you ask a new question about that. (Maybe you want to delete this question. Its of limited general value.)